# Normalize list of associative arrays to write to CSV

Tags: php, arrays, csv

Given an array of the form

```
[
    ['id' => 1, 'name' => 'foo', 'description' => 'the foo described'],
    ['id' => 2, 'name' => 'bar'],
    ['id' => 3, 'description' => 'the one that shall not be named'],
]
```

i.e. each element is an associative array where most values are optional.

What's the best way to export it to a CSV file?

```
"id","name","description"
"1","foo","the foo described"
"2","bar",""
"3","","the one that shall not be named"
```

To do so, I probably need to convert the array to this:

```
[
    ['id' => 1, 'name' => 'foo', 'description' => 'the foo described'],
    ['id' => 2, 'name' => 'bar', 'description' => ''],
    ['id' => 3, 'name' => '', 'description' => 'the one that shall not be named'],
]
```

If it helps:

- the keys are always in the same order
- a list of all possible keys can be generated if necessary

Are there any tricks with PHP array functions that I can apply?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [`array_fill_keys`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-fill-keys.php), [`array_map`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-map.php) and [`array_merge`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-merge.php) for your issue:

```
<?php
$keys = ['id', 'name', 'description'];
$template = array_fill_keys($keys, '');

$array = [
    ['id' => '1', 'name' => 'foo', 'description' => 'description 1'],
    ['id' => '2', 'name' => 'bar'],
    ['id' => '3', 'description' => 'description 2']
];

$normalized = array_map(function($item) use ($template) {
    return array_merge($template, $item);
}, $array);
```